# drawing objects size is too small

Tags: tikz-pgf, framed

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{epic}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[remember picture, overlay] \draw[line width=1pt] ($(current page.north west)+(1in, -.5in) $)rectangle($(current page.south east)+(-.5in, 1in) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{picture}(100,13)
\begin{dottedjoin}{2}
\jput(0,0){\circle{3}}
\jput(20,8){\makebox(0,0){\Large$\star$}}
\jput(40,3){\makebox(0,0){\small Finish}}
\end{dottedjoin}
\begin{dashjoin}[20]{3}
\jput(55,3){}
\jput(70,10){\oval(10,5)}
\jput(80,0){\circle*{2}}
\end{dashjoin}
\end{picture}
\begin{picture}(100,13)
\dottedline[.]{3}(0,0)(10,10)(20,0)
\dashline{3}(30,0)(40,10)(50,0)
\drawline(60,0)(70,10)(80,0)
\end{picture}
 \put(1.8,1.2){An arrow}\\
\put(1.5,1.2){\framebox(2.5,1.2){center}} \\
\put(0.0,1.95){\framebox(2,1.0)
[t]{top center}}\\
\put(3.0,1.95){\framebox(2,0.8)
[lb]{bot. left}}\\
\put(3.0,3.2){\framebox(2,0.6)
[r]{center right}}\\
\put(2.0,0.3){\framebox(2,0.6)
[s]{stretch\hfill center}}\\


%\put(3,1.6){\makebox(0,0){center center}}
%\put(2,0.5){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{top right}}
%\put(4,1.0){\makebox(0,0)[b]{bot center}}
%\put(2,2.8){\makebox(0,0)[l]{flush left}}

%
%\thicklines
%\put(0,0){\line(1,0){6}}\\
%\put(0,0){\line(0,1){1}}\\
%\put(6,0){\line(0,1){0.5}}\\

\begin{picture}(5,2)\thicklines
\put(5,0){\vector(-1,0){5}}
\put(0,0){\vector(1,1){2}}
\put(2,2){\vector(3,-2){3}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

the above code gives me output which is very small as shown in the picture
[image]

secondly how do i overlay written material inside of the rectangle--the drawings shift to the second page--how do i keep them on the first page inside the frame rectangle

Comment: Why you not use `tikz` for drawing of images?

Comment: Why is this tagged `tikz-pgf`?